# Product cards image resize automatically

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am creating a CRUD application for an ecommerce website. I am trying to display the product cards. However, I would like to ensure that every image uploaded will be automatically resized in order for the cards to be aligned no matter what.

[image: here is a screenshot]

HTML with Bootstrap:

```
<div className="card h-100">
    <a href="#!">
        <img
            className="img-fluid w-100 img-card"
            src={`/uploads/${product.fileName}`}
            alt="product"
        />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-card{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image you are using might be different resolution this is
my Usual Approach for this:

**Method 1**

```
 <div className="card h-100">
    <a href="#!">
     <div class="img-container">
      <img
        className="img-fluid w-100 img-card"
        src={`/uploads/${product.fileName}`}
        alt="product"
      />
    </div>
    </a>
</div>

.img-container {
   position: relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   height: 300px; (your wish)
}

.img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover
}
```

**Method 2**

Using Aspect Ratio https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp

```
.img-container {
   padding-bottom: 75%; 
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover
}
```